# Having Regex Troubles

Tags: regex, bash

Could really use some Regex help.

I am trying to create bash IF statements that would throw a specific error message if it encounters any of three separate text conditions.

The first is when a series of 6 alphanumeric numbers is followed by only a comma

```
WA16B7, 
1AAA42, 
5A5CC5,
```

The first is when a series of 6 alphanumeric numbers is followed by either nothing or space(s).

```
WA16B7
1AAA42
5A5CC5
```

The third is when a series of 6 alphanumeric numbers is followed by a space, or series of spaces and then other random text.

```
WA16B7 Test1
1AAA42  Test2
5A5CC5   Test3
```

On the other hand, I need the following values to pass without errors:

```
WA16B7, Test1
1AAA42, Test2
5A5CC5, Test3
```

The basic gist of the code should look something like this, where the textLines is read from a text file. I just don't know the proper regex syntax for each condition that would still allow for the text above and in which order to put them so that they are caught as encountered.

```
if ! [[ $textLines =~ [A-Z0-9]{6}[[:space:]]*,+ ]]; then
        echo "Error: A"
        continue
fi

if ! [[ $textLines =~ [A-Z0-9]{6}[[:space:]]*,+ ]]; then
        echo "Error: B"
        continue
fi

if ! [[ $textLines =~ [A-Z0-9]{6}[[:space:]]*,+ ]]; then
        echo "Error: C"
        continue
fi
```

Comment: Why are you using `{13}` if you want to test for strings of 6 characters?

Comment: Also, note that right now your regexes are all unanchored. If you want them to only match at the start of the string, start them with `^`.

Comment: `^[A-Z0-9],$` matches 6 characters followed by only a comma. `^[A-Z0-9], *$` matches 6 characters followed by a comma and some spaces.  `^[A-Z0-9] *$` matches 6 characters followed by either nothing or some spaces.

Comment: Anyhow -- can you narrow this down to a more specific question, other than something that reads as "please fill in every blank between the code I have and the code I need"? Right now this is really quite broad of a question.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what would be something that should not result in an error?  If you can't have 6 characters followed by nothing, followed by spaces, followed by a comma, or followed by random text, then what should work?

Comment: Yes, corrected that. It should be 6 of course.

Comment: WA16B7, Test1 should not result in an error.

Comment: Forgive me but I am very new to this :-)

Comment: so like this?  if ! [[ $textLines =~ ^[A-Z0-9],$; then
        echo "Error: A"
        continue
fi

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much.

Comment: Actually, only the first one (^[A-Z0-9],$) works. ^[A-Z0-9], *$ throws a syntax error in conditional expression error.

Comment: Also need one for 6 alphanumeric numbers followed by a space, or series of spaces and then other random text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did using python.

> File

```
WA16B7,
1AAA42,
5A5CC5,
WA16B7
1AAA42
5A5CC5
WA16B7 Test1
1AAA42  Test2
5A5CC5   Test3
WA16B7, Test1
1AAA42, Test2
5A5CC5, Test3
```

> Script

```py
import re

def test(text):
    if re.search('\w{6}, \w{1,}', text):
        return f'OK'
    elif re.search('\w{6}, ?',text):
        return f'Erro 1'
    elif re.search('\w{6} ?',text):
        return f'Erro 2'

with open(file='a.txt',mode='r') as input_file:
    list_lines = input_file.read().splitlines()
    for i in list_lines:
        print(f'Result: {test(i)} | word: {i}')
```

> Result

```
Result: Erro 1 | word: WA16B7,
Result: Erro 1 | word: 1AAA42,
Result: Erro 1 | word: 5A5CC5,
Result: Erro 2 | word: WA16B7
Result: Erro 2 | word: 1AAA42
Result: Erro 2 | word: 5A5CC5
Result: Erro 2 | word: WA16B7 Test1
Result: Erro 2 | word: 1AAA42  Test2
Result: Erro 2 | word: 5A5CC5   Test3
Result: OK | word: WA16B7, Test1
Result: OK | word: 1AAA42, Test2
Result: OK | word: 5A5CC5, Test3
```